# How do I spawn a minecraft zombie with custom armor / shield / sword / item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Could someone tell me please? I really need to know for my new adventure map.

Comment: We'll need more details to work out your problem. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a command block since the command is long.

You spawn a zombie with shield, armor, and sword by typing this command in a command block:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~2~1~ {handItems:[{id:minecraft:(item),Count1),{id:minecraft:(item),Count1)}]}
```

You can add as many items as you want, here is an example:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~2~1~ {handItems:[{id:minecraft:diamond_sword,Count1),{id:minecrat:shield,Count1),{id:minecraft:lether_boots,Count1},{id:minecraft:diamond_chestplate,Count1)}]}
```

For more information:

Comment: So close, but nonetheless incorrect. Your NBT is malformed. Check again?